# Increment distance in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, increment

I have

```
data: {  
                CategoryID:"xxx",
                SubCategories:"true",
                MaxDistanceKM:"50",
                SecurityToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },

              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
            userData3.success(function (userdataobject) {
              $scope.catadata3 = userdataobject;
            });
```

**Problem:** If no record found in 50 Kilo Meter, make `MaxDistanceKM:"100"`.
If record not found in 100, make `MaxDistanceKM:"150"`

Increase 50 every time if record not found.

Comment: Could you post a more explicit code ? What's `catadata3` for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```js
function request(km) {
  $http.get(url, {
    MaxDistanceKM: km
  }).success(function(data) {
    if(!data) {
      request(km + 50);
    } else {
      $scope.catadata3 = data;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a little refactor in your code but it should be something like that:

```
var currentKM = 50;

function getRequestData(){
    data: {  
        CategoryID:"xxx",
        SubCategories:"true",
        MaxDistanceKM: currentKm,
        SecurityToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
}

function fireRequest(){
    var request = getRequestData();

    $.ajax(request).success(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(userdataobject) {
   //I don't know whaty userdataobject contains but let's assume it has `results` and I can check if it's 0 or not.
   if(userdataobject.results.length === 0){
       currentKm += 50;
       fireRequest();
   }else{
       $scope.catadata3 = userdataobject;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers , you have to understand what's going on.

Let's create a simulation for AJAX request :

```
function get(distance)
{
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (distance === 300)
                resolve(true);
          else reject(distance);

        }, 1000)

    });

    return p;

}
```

That function will return `true` asynchronously only when the value passed in is 300. ( we start at 0,100,200,300).

then let's create a function which will call that function :

```
function request(distance)
{
    get(distance).then(function(data)
    {
        console.log('found ' + data)
        alert(data);
    }, function(data)
    {
        console.log('not-found ' + data);
        request(data + 100)
    })
}
```

Now , we start with `request(0)`

If the response is not resolved , then we call `get` again with the incremented value.

[**Please see full demo here. (open the console).**](http://jsbin.com/nuwaqu/2/edit?html,js,output)